# Grouped bar chart on R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

How do I create a grouped bar chart on R using `ggplot2` using this data?

```
Person Cats Dogs

Mr. A   3   1

Mr. B   4   2
```

So that it shows that shows number of pets owned per person, with this layout [Bar chart of pets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWzFP.png)

I have a text file with this data and have used `read.delim` to read the file on R.

I have used this code but it does not produce the bar plot I am looking for.

```
ggplot(data=pets, aes(x=Person, y=Cats, fill=Dogs)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

I am new to R, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To prepare data for grouped bar plot, use `melt()` function of `reshape2` package

I. Loading required packages

```
    library(reshape2)
    library(ggplot2)
```

II. Creating data frame `df`

```
    df <- data.frame(Person = c("Mr.A","Mr.B"), Cats = c(3,4), Dogs = c(1,2))
    df
    #   Person Cats Dogs
    # 1   Mr.A    3    1
    # 2   Mr.B    4    2
```

III. Melting data using `melt` function

```
    data.m <- melt(df, id.vars='Person')
    data.m
    #   Person variable value
    # 1   Mr.A     Cats     3
    # 2   Mr.B     Cats     4
    # 3   Mr.A     Dogs     1
    # 4   Mr.B     Dogs     2
```

IV. Grouped Bar plot by `Person`

```
   ggplot(data.m, aes(Person, value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), 
   width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity") +  
   theme(legend.position="top", legend.title = 
   element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
   axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Legend on top, legend title removed, axis titles removed, adjusted bar widths and space between bars.

[image]

Comment: by far the best explanation that I have found by now online